# Рекурсивная функция python

Tags: python

Написать рекурсивную функцию для подсчета суммы чисел в списке. Почему не рекурсия не работает ?

```
def summ_l(*args):
    summ = 0
    if args[len(args)-1] == args[0]:
        return 1
    return  summ + summ_l(args[len(args)-1])

print(summ_l(42, 24, 15, 18))
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос словестное описание процесса подсчета как вы его задумали.

Comment: возьмите карандаш и пройдите по всем рекурсивным вызовам (их получится не так и много, всего один, независимо от длины исходных данных), и все станет ясно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот такое решение вам подойдёт?

```
def summ_l(n):
    if not n:
        return 0
    return n[0] + summ_l(n[1:])

print(summ_l([42, 24, 15, 18]))
```